# Changing mono font with PDFLaTeX

Tags: fonts, typewriter, oldstylenums

I'd like to change the default monofont (used with `\texttt{}` and `\url{}`) to "CMU Typewriter Text Variable Width", without touching the default main font.

I was able to do it with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=.935]{CMU Typewriter Text Variable Width}
```

But [`fontspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) forces me to change the compiler to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, both of which I don't like as they ignore `\oldstylenums{}`.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: it is certainly easier to solve your problem with \oldstylenums than to create pdflatex support for an unicode font. So better ask a question with an example showing your real problem.

Comment: using a variable width font as monospace is something of  logical contradicton (although may be a convenient way to introduce the font)

Comment: Not sure what is meant here as example to be honest, whenever I use \oldstylenums{} in the main text, the number is "printed" in the output pdf with titling figures when using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. It is instead correctly printed with old style figures when I use PDFLaTeX. I should probably say that I don't want old style figures to be the default throughout the document, as I am only using them for displaying years (e.g. "august \oldstylenums{1899}", but "10 kW"). I hope that's helpful

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah basically I want the urls to standout but I am not a fan of fixed width fonts so the variable width typewriter font seems a good compromise

Comment: using the font makes sense, calling it monospace less so you can use it for `\url` without using it for ttfamily.   for pdftex why Unicode? `\fontfamily{lmvt}\selectfont` is latin modern variable typewriter

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe the BiBTeX compiler uses ttfamily for urls (in the .bbl document I read `\csname url@tt\endcsname`). But if there is an easier way to change the default ttfamily font I'd gladly to that.

Comment: no,bibtex knows nothing about fonts or url

Comment: so presumably with that bibstyle you want `\def\url@tt{\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont}`  so urls use variable tt

Comment: Anything else than `\csname url@samestyle\endcsname` displays urls using the monospace font. (I tried: `\csname url@tt{\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont}\endcsname`, `\csname url@lmvtt\endcsname`, `\csname url@vtt\endcsname`, among others)

Comment: `\csname url@tt{\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont` that clearly will error! the content of `csname` has to expand to a command name, not select a font

Comment: if your unshown code is using `\csname url@tt\endcsname` then it wants you to do as I suggest above and define `\url@tt`

Comment: `cfr-lm` supports this either as the default `\ttfamily` or on a case-by-case basis. It uses old style proportional numerals by default, but you only have to change the package options to either proportional lining or proportional tabular. That will give you Latin Modern which is the `lmvtt` @DavidCarlisle is referring to.

Comment: @cfr probably worth a second answer, you might even steal a tick:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle for the sake of clarity, the original .bst document had `\csname url@samestyle\endcsname` which displayed urls using the roman serif font. I found that by changing `samestyle` to anything else, the url font becomes the defaulted monospace font (I wrote `tt` but, for example, `it` weirdly has the same effect). I don't know if there is a way to get urls to be displayed with the `\tvfamily`. That would be handy as I wouldn't have to change the default for `\ttfamily` then.

Comment: change `\csname url@samestyle\endcsname`  to  `\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont` and re-run bibtex

Comment: That changed the wole biblio text to tv, not URLs only

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don't you want something like `\csname url@tmlcstyle\endcsname` (in conjunction with the code in my answer) or `\csname url@ttstyle\endcsname`. At least, that's what the `url` documentation suggests to me. I don't know why a `.bst` would hard-code the style, though.

Comment: @FlipTis Neither LuaLaTeX nor XeLaTeX ignore `\oldstylenums`. Maybe you tried using `fontspec` but never ran `\setmainfont`? `fontspec` changes how `\oldstylenums` works so after you load it it will only work with fontspec loaded fonts, but you can make it work again by reloading the default fonts e.g. with `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I didn't know that! You guessed correctly, I didn't run `\setmainfont`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cfr-lm` provides access to all four families of figures in Latin Modern, as well as variable and monowidth typewriter. Access to upright italic and italic small-caps is also provided.

[image: variations in Latin Modern]

You choose what is default. You can also switch between figure and typewriter styles as needed.

However, in preparing this example, I discovered an undeclared dependency in the package, so you need to load `ifthen` first. (I guess so many things load `ifthen`, I've never noticed despite using `cfr-lm` for years.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[rm={lining},sf={lining},tt={tabular,lining,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}
% \usepackage[rm={lining},sf={lining},tt={proportional,lining,variable}]{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
  one two three four five 0123456789
  
  \texttt{one two three four five 0123456789}

  % select variable typewriter with proportional lining figures when 
  % monowidth with tabular lining is default
  \texttv{\textpl{one two three four five 0123456789}}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use the light, condensed monowidth typewriter as the font `\texttm` produces, add the following line to your preamble after loading `cfr-lm`.

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand\texttm{\tmstyle\lgweight\cdwidth}
```

Then `\texttm{Hello world!}` will produce

[image: light, condensed, monowidth Latin Modern typewriter]

**EDIT EDIT**

I cannot say whether this will change what your bibliography style does with URLs since I don't know anything about your setup. However, the following results in monowidth, light, condensed Latin Modern typewriter being used for URLs typeset with, for example, `\url{*<URL>*}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[rm={lining},sf={lining},tt={proportional,lining,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}% 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tmlcstyle}{%       monowidth, light, condensed typewriter
  \tmstyle\lgweight\cdwidth}
% \DeclareTextFontCommand\texttmlc{\tmlcstyle}% create a new command
\DeclareTextFontCommand\texttm{\tmlcstyle}% overwrite the package's \texttm
\def\url@tmlcstyle{%
 \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\tt}}{\def\UrlFont{\tmlcstyle}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{tmlc}

\begin{document}
  one two three four five 0123456789
  
  \texttt{one two three four five 0123456789}

  % select variable typewriter with proportional lining figures when 
  % monowidth with tabular lining is default
  \texttv{\textpl{one two three four five 0123456789}}
  
  \texttm{Hello world!}
  
  \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}
  

\end{document}
```

[image: use of Latin Modern typewriter monowidth light condensed for a URL]

In contrast, here's the result with `tt` as the URL style:

[image: use of standard Latin Modern typewriter for a URL]

Comment: Ok this works fine (I used `tt={proportional,lining,variable}`) is there any way to make the tt text narrower, or at least smaller? (I scaled it to 93.5% originally, as can be seen in the code from my original question)

Comment: @FlipTis Not at present. Nobody asked before ;). However, the package is going to need to be updated due to the error - actually, it needs updating anyway - so I could look into how easy that might be. I think it might just be a question of including a factor in the `.fd` files, in which case I could probably do it without having to regenerate everything. But I'm not certain about that. If it needs changes to the `.tfm`s, that's a bigger job. Generating the files for this package takes a *long* time on my machine. So I wouldn't necessarily get to that imminently.

Comment: ok that looks promising enough! In the meanwile i was trying
`\usepackage[rm={proportional,lining},sf={lining},tt={proportional,lining,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}`
`\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\texttt{\textlg{\textcd{#1}}}}`
but it seems to bug the compiler, so I tried
`\renewcommand{\texttm}[1]{\texttm{\textlg{\textcd{#1}}}}`
which is compiled fine but doesn't switch to light condensed monowidth typewriter

Comment: @FlipTis `\texttm{\textlg{\textcd{Hello, world!}}}` gives the expected output. The code you're using isn't the way you'd normally define something like `\texttm`. I'm not sure of the details of the whys, but `\DeclareTextFontCommand` is the usual how. Notice that the definitions you've given are circular. At the very least, you'd need to save the current definition to a new name in order to use it in redefining itself. Use `\DeclareTextFontCommand\texttm{\tmstyle\lgweight\cdwidth}` to redefine `\texttm`. Or you can redefine `\texttt` this way, if you prefer.

Comment: @FlipTis I'm surprised the second one compiles, to be honest. The difference may be because recent LaTeX handles fonts a bit differently than when `nfssext-cfr` was written, which is what `cfr-lm` is using to access the full range of weights, widths, figure styles etc. For most purposes, the differences don't matter at the document level, but it might be worth saying that `nfssext-cfr` is manipulating the names of families and font definition files which use the Karl Berry naming scheme. This is a bit old-fashioned, but enabled support not then o/w possible (and still not in some cases).

Comment: @FlipTis Note that `proportional` is default so `sf={lining}` still gets you proportional figures. If you want tabular, you need `sf={lining,tabular}`. You might want that if you use sans in tables, for example, while using serif with proportional figures in the body of the text.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the code from the above comment, since comments here are ephemeral. @FlipTis

Comment: Ok thank you again. Basically I don't have any sans text in the document and I'm ok with all numerals being proportional by default, regardless of the font. When using typewriter text for standing out I found that `\texttv{}` is the best option for me.

Comment: Now to URLs. I am using `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}\urlstyle{tt}` currently, but the text is _way_ too wide. So I tried `\usepackage[rm={lining},sf={lining},tt={proportional,lining,monowidth}]{cfr-lm}` and `\DeclareTextFontCommand\texttt{\tmstyle\lgweight\cdwidth}` and I also added `\csname url@ttstyle\endcsname` to the .bst file, hoping that the bibliography would use condensed typewriter font for URLs, but it keeps using regular typewriter text instead, for some reason. Could you help with this?

Comment: @FlipTis I think you might want to ask a new question for that. I haven't used a `.bst` for ages. Reference this question/answer and include a minimal example using your bibliography style etc. so people know what they're working with. I'm not sure if this is a matter of the `.bst` or any bibliography package you're loading ....

Comment: Ok but I think the problem lies with the `url` or `hyperref` package rather, as the output will give regular typewriter text (ie not condensed) if i write something within `\url{}` in the main document body. The .bst file should be alright

Comment: @FlipTis Sorry. I just realised the problem. You need a style type command for that, but look at the url/hyperref docs first. There's a standard way of defining the font to use for URLs. If that has to use one of the standard families, you'd need to redefine `\ttfamily` or hack something to force it to use something else. Otherwise, you might be able to just define it as `\tmstyle\lgweight\cdwidth`. The command I gave above doesn't change the `\ttfamily` or even `\tmstyle`. It **only** changes the high-level `\text**` command, which isn't what hyperref/url is using.

Comment: This is the definition of `url@ttstyle`:
`\def\url@ttstyle{\@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\tt}}{\def\UrlFont{\ttfamily}}}` any idea what should I redefine?

Comment: @FlipTis Please see edit above. I can't say whether this will change the output in your bibliography. If not, I think that would best be a new question because somebody who knows the `.bst` side of things may be able to help. But it does get URLs typeset in the desired font. I'm rather surprised this worked, to be honest, because the documentation says math mode is used and I more-or-less expected it to fail for that reason.

Comment: Yes! It worked perfectly as intended, cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 7):

If using pdftex you can use the original latin modern variable typewriter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

One two three four five six.

{\ttfamily One two three four five six.}

{\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont One two three four five six.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can make that the default with `\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmvtt}` but you could use it for url without changing the tt family

Comment: This worked as intended, thank you!

Comment: @FlipTis Note that this will, I think, get you tabular lining figures rather than proportional lining. Latin Modern had four styles of figures ....

Comment: @cfr you mean in the tt font?

Comment: @FlipTis In all of them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not sure about the tick, but I found an error in the package despite using it for years. It depends on an obscure package called `ifthen`.

Comment: @cfr this one? https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64275789#64275789